# how to make inro page for website, it show only one time per visitor

Tags: php, cookies

I wanna make intro page or popup in website with two buttons accept and decline. If customer click accept intro page didin't shows see in future for visitors which click accept. I know that script can make with cookies, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two trivial ways.

PHP way (on your homepage):

```
// did they accept to enter site? if there is not a cookie then no
if (!isset($_COOKIE['enter']))
{
     header("Location: intro.php");
     die();  
}
```

On intro.php, process when the user accepts to access the site. To set the cookie, do:

```
setcookie("enter", true);
```

Or you could use [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to check if the cookie is set or not using JavaScript. If it isn't, show the JavaScript modal popup.

Hopefully this pushes you in the right direction. Good luck!

Comment: Now i must creat intro.php with form accept and decline whose sent to next php file which inform or visitor click accept or decline, if visitor accept hes browser save cookies and visitor will be redirected to index.php?maybe you can write full code?

Comment: That's exactly how you'll do it. Good luck.